# Get a number of elements from a specified starting index

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Let's say I have a simple array like this:
`var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I'd like to `extract a number of elements, starting from a specific index`, like this:

```
myArr.getElementsFromIndex(index, numberOfElements)
```

where, `unlike .slice()`, if we hit the last index,  elements from the start of the array should be returned instead (so that the total number of elements returned will always be respected). Either pure javascript or a library like underscore/lodash can be used.

Examples:

```
myArr.getElementsFromIndex(3, 5)
```

should return`[3,4,5,6,7]`
and

```
myArr.getElementsFromIndex(8, 5)
```

should return `[8,9,0,1,2]`

Comment: And what would be result of `myArr.getElementsFromIndex(8, 12)`?

Comment: Interesting bordercase scenario - in this case we should get the following array [8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) takes a start and end index (not a start index and a number of elements).

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does what you want, except for the wrapping around (but also modifies the original array).

You can write a wrapper function using slice (which will not modify the original array):

```
function getElementsFromIndex(arr, start, numElements) {
    if(start + numElements > arr.length) {
        var endOfArr = arr.slice(start, arr.length);
        var elementsFound = arr.length - start;
        var restElements = getElementsFromIndex(arr, 0, numElements - elementsFound);
        return endOfArr.concat(restElements);
    }
    return arr.slice(start, start + numElements);
}
```

This function returns what you require ([see example](http://jsfiddle.net/7jtakjcp/)), and even wraps around multiple times, if needed.

If you want to tie the function to arrays, in order to use it as you propose (ie. `myArr.getElementsFromIndex(start, numElements)`), you can add it to `Array`'s prototype. You might want to look up arguments for/against modifying prototypes of built-in types, though.

```
Array.prototype.getElementsFromIndex = function(start, numElements) {
    if(start + numElements > this.length) {
        var endOfArr = this.slice(start, this.length);
        var elementsFound = this.length - start;
        return endOfArr.concat(this.getElementsFromIndex(0, numElements - elementsFound));
    }
    return this.slice(start, start + numElements);
};
```

[See example of the last one here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7jtakjcp/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function getElementsFromIndex(startIndex, num) {

    var elems = [];
    for(var iter = 0; iter<num; iter++) {
        if(startIndex >= myArr.length) {
            while(startIndex >= myArr.length) {
               startIndex -=  myArr.length;
            }
        } 
        elems.push(myArr[startIndex]);
        startIndex++;
    }
    return(elems);
}
```

Comment: `getElementsFromIndex(30,4);` results: `[undefined, undefined, 2, 3]` I think it should result: `[undefined, undefined, defined, undefined]`

Comment: Updated the code. getElementsFromIndex(30,4) should return [0,1,2,3], as the OP wants to wrap around, if the index falls outside array length.

Comment: Your `while` section is essentially a wordy version of the modulo `%` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your js code:

```
Array.prototype.getElementsFromIndex = function (start, len) {
    var newArray = [],
        origArray = this,
        i = start;

    while (newArray.length < len) {
        newArray.push(origArray[i++]);

        if (i >= origArray.length)
            i = 0;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

**You can use it exactly the way you wanted**:

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
alert(myArr.getElementsFromIndex(8, 5));
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/x6oy0krL/1

Maybe some people will say that it is not right to extend objects like Array, documentElement and so on, but the result here is as the OP wanted.

I want to say that the original array will not be modified, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the array to itself, then use slice:

```
 function sliceWrap(arr, start, num) {
     return arr.concat(arr).slice(start, start+num); 
}
```

Another approach, which wraps around:

```
function sliceWrap2(arr, start, num) {
    var result = [], i, end = start+num, len = arr.length;
    for (i=start; i<end; i++) {
        result.push(arr[i % len]);
    }
    return result;
}
```